# XLSX parsing using Spreadsheet::XLSX

Tags: perl, parsing, spreadsheet, xlsx

I have a script that will do parsing for xls like:

```
$parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(
                                     CellHandler => sub {$self->handle_cell(@_) },
                                     NotSetCell  => 1
                                        );
```

Now I am modifying this to parse xlsx file and it seems like xlsx file will not take any parameters in `new()`

And `handle_cell` function, we get sheet_index and workbook and

> ```
> $worksheet = $workbook->Worksheet($sheet_index);
>  $worksheet->row_range();
> ```

I want to give parameters like CellHandler and NotSetCell to `Spreadsheet::XLSX` also. But I came to know that `Spreadsheet::XLSX` doen't take any parameters. Do we have any other Perl module that acts same as Spreadsheet::ParseExcel but for parsing xlsx?

Please help me in this. Is there any other Perl module for parsing xlsx by passing arguments to new()?

Comment: Any method to reduce the memory usage in Spreadsheet::XLSX?

Answer (score 2):

There's a project started at github: [Excel-Reader-XLSX](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-reader-xlsx). It isn't fancy but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  [This is what I use.](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX)

It has an api like the parse excel module, and can deal with xlsx files.
Look through the doc.  There is a paragraph or two about things you can do to reduce the memory foot print.